# How to close current Dialog before opening another one?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dialog, modal-dialog

This is my Login modal:

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";

import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTrigger } from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
} from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { siteConfig } from "@/config/site";
import { Button, buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { ModeToggle } from "../mode-toggle";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { RegisterModal } from "@/components/auth/register-modal";

interface LoginModalProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  asChild?: boolean;
}

export function LoginModal({ children, asChild }: LoginModalProps) {
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger asChild={asChild}>{children}</DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="p-0 w-auto bg-transparent border-none">
        <Card className="w-[400px] shadow-md">
          <CardHeader>
            <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-y-4 items-start justify-start">
              <Link href="/">
                <div className="mr-6 flex items-center space-x-2">
                  <Icons.logo className="h-6 w-6" />
                  <span className="hidden font-bold sm:inline-block">
                    {siteConfig.name}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <div className="gap-y-0.5">
                <p className="text-3xl font-bold">Login</p>
                <p className="text-muted-foreground text-sm">
                  to access exclusive content on XXXXXX
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardContent>Login Form!</CardContent>
          <CardFooter>
            <div className="flex items-center w-full gap-x-2">
              <Button
                size="lg"
                className="w-full"
                variant="outline"
                onClick={() => {}}
              >
                <Icons.google className="h-5 w-5" />
              </Button>
              <Button
                size="lg"
                className="w-full"
                variant="outline"
                onClick={() => {}}
              >
                <Icons.discord className="h-5 w-5" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          </CardFooter>
          <CardFooter>
            <div
              className={cn(
                buttonVariants({
                  variant: "link",
                  size: "sm",
                }),
                "text-secondary-foreground font-normal w-full items-start justify-start"
              )}
              onClick={onClose}
            >
              <RegisterModal>
                Don&apos;t have an account?
              </RegisterModal>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-2 justify-end">
              <nav className="flex items-center">
                <Link
                  href={siteConfig.links.discord}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                >
                  <div
                    className={cn(
                      buttonVariants({
                        variant: "ghost",
                      }),
                      "w-9 px-0"
                    )}
                  >
                    <Icons.discord className="h-4 w-4" />
                    <span className="sr-only">Discord</span>
                  </div>
                </Link>
                <Link
                  href={siteConfig.links.twitter}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                >
                  <div
                    className={cn(
                      buttonVariants({
                        variant: "ghost",
                      }),
                      "w-9 px-0"
                    )}
                  >
                    <Icons.twitter className="h-3 w-3 fill-current" />
                    <span className="sr-only">Twitter</span>
                  </div>
                </Link>
                <ModeToggle />
              </nav>
            </div>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

I have wrapped Already have an account button with Register Modal! Register Modal is exactly like this Login Modal. But Register Modal opens on top of the Login Modal without closing the login Modal! I want to the Login Modal to close when register modal is opened!

I don't have any clue on how to do this!

Comment: guess you've to handle it using css.
Even if we try to control the visibility of LoginModal by using states, it might not work as expected because RegisterModal is still a child of LoginModal.

Comment: Isn't there any other approach other than CSS!